# Identify string constants in source code at compile time

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a requirement to check if a specific string constant is used in source code in a Scala project built with SBT.

```
class Test {
  def f(s: String) = {
    val na = s"... from t2_trans where na_id > 300"
    ...
    na
}
```

I would like to catch the string `t2_` is used in class `Test` when I compile/build the project.

Any libraries to get this done?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If a `String` literal, somewhere in your source code, contains the substring `"t2_"`, what do you want the compiler to do? Issue a warning and continue? Or, report the error and halt compilation? Or, ...?

Comment: needs to abort the compilation with an error showing which file caused it.

Comment: I don't know. It might be possible via macros and/or a compiler plug-in, but I'm not aware of any.